# Moment Generating Function of Given PDF : $f(x) = 1/2 e^x $ when $x<0$ and $= e^{-2x}$ when $x > 0$

Tags: moments, moment-generating-function

To derive moment generating function(mgf) of $f(x) = 1/2 e^x $ when $x<0$ and $= e^{-2x}$ when $x > 0$,

Since mgf $M(t) = E(e^{tx})$, we get

$E(e^{tx}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\cdot f(e^{tx})dx = \int_0^\infty e^{tx}\cdot e^{-2e^{tx}} + \int_{-\infty}^0e^{tx}\cdot {1\over 2}e^{e^{tx}}$

But is there any way to integrte into more simple format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your formula for the moment generating function is wrong.

$$E(e^{tX})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-2x}dx+\int_{-\infty}^0e^{tx}\frac{1}{2}e^{x}dx$$

Then you can start from here to calculate the $M(t)$. It should  not be very difficult.

Comment: Note that the random variable is $X$; the equation is $E(e^{tX}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f(x) dx$

Answer (score 2):

An alternative viewpoint is that $X$ has a *mixture* density that consists of an equally-weighted sum of the density of an *exponential* random variable with parameter $2$ (the 
$e^{-2x}\mathbf 1_{\{x>0\}} = \frac 12\cdot 2e^{-2x} \mathbf 1_{\{x>0\}}$ part) and the density of the *negative* of an *exponential* random variable with parameter $1$ (the $\frac 12 e^{x}\mathbf 1_{\{x<0\}} = \frac 12\cdot e^{x} \mathbf 1_{\{x<0\}}$ part). Consequently, the MGF of $X$ is the equally weighted sum of the MGFs of these two densities, and the region of convergence of the MGFs is the *intersection* of the regions of convergence of the MGFs of the mixture components.